# using weights in the simulate() function in R

Tags: r, glm, simulate

I want to generate predicted values of a GLM function including stochastic uncertainty. I use 2 approaches and compare them to make sure its correct.

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(MASS) 
n <- 1500 
d <- mvrnorm(n=n, mu=c(0,0,0,0),Sigma=matrix(.7, nrow=4, ncol=4) + diag(4)*.3) 
d[,1] <- qgamma(p=pnorm(q=d[,1]), shape=2, rate=2) * 1000 
m <- glm(formula=d[,1] ~ d[,2] + d[,3] + d[,4], family=gaussian(link="sqrt")) 
p_lin <- m$coef[1] + m$coef[2]*d[,2] + m$coef[3]*d[,3] + m$coef[4]*d[,4]
p1 <- rnorm(n=n, mean=p_lin^2, sd=sd(p_lin^2 - d[,1])) 
p2 <- simulate(m)$sim_1

par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(4,2,2,1), pch=16, cex=0.8, pty="s") 
xylim <- c(min(c(d[,1], p1, p2)), max(c(d[,1], p1, p2))) 
plot(x=d[,1], y=p1, xlab="predicted values", ylab="original data", xlim=xylim, ylim=xylim, col=rgb(0,0,0,alpha=0.1)) 
points(x=d[,1], y=simulate(m)$sim_1, col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.1))
abline(a=0, b=1, col="red")
```

The predictions differ. Looking at the source code of the simulate() function 
(this can be done by using:

```
getS3method(c("predict"), class = "glm")
```

)

I see that the simulate() function applies a weighted-based sd:

```
if (!is.null(object$weights)) 
vars <- vars/object$weights ftd + rnorm(ntot, sd = sqrt(vars)) # this is the prediction including stochastic uncertainty; ftd is defined as fitted(object)
```

Looking at the help function I read that "The methods for linear models fitted by lm or glm(family = "gaussian") assume that any weights which have been supplied are inversely proportional to the error variance." However, I assume this is about the prior weights, which I did not apply and are NULL (m$prior.weights). However, the simulate function seems to use the m$weights, which seems identical to 4*m$fitted.values. I googled a lot but can't get to the bottom of this. Why does the simulate() function apply these weights in the sd? Is this correct? How are these weights calculated?
(its related to the post: [microsimulation GLM including stochastic part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213806/microsimulation-glm-including-stochastic-part); hopefully I'm not wrong in starting a new one)

Comment: This seems more like a statistical methodological question than a programming one. If that's the case you'd be better off asking your statistical questions over at [stats.se] where such matters are on-topic.

Comment: A GLM can be fitted using weighted least squares applied iteratively until the coefficient estimates converge. Hence the GLM is a weighted linear model, which is where those weights come from.